# Filter coefficients conversion from Matlab for FPGA, follow up

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design

My question is a follow up of [original question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82859/filter-coefficients-conversion-from-matlab-for-fpga), specifically the answer provided by @Dan Boschen [Dans answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/82859/filter-coefficients-conversion-from-matlab-for-fpga#:%7E:text=The%20coefficients%20are%20scaled%20to%20the%20maximum%20allowed:%7E:text=The%20coefficients%20are%20scaled%20to%20the%20maximum%20allowed).
The question is about converting floating point coefficients to fixed point signed numbers.
I am comparing Dan's answer to [Surf VHDL Fixed Point](https://surf-vhdl.com/how-to-quantize-fir-coefficient/#:%7E:text=Fixed%2Dpoint%20representation%20of%20an%20FIR%20coefficient) which does the same thing differently.

I understand Dan's answer and makes sense to me as the correct way to quantize floating point coefficients to fixed point signed numbers.

Comparing Dan's answer to the Surf VHDL answer, the Surf VHDL method is different and may have an issue.
Surf VHDL first normalizes (like Dan), however Surf VHDL normalizes positive values to MaxPos (the largest positive coefficient) and negative values to MaxNeg.
It seems like the Surf VHDL method has the potential to create accuracy issues in the signal by multiplying positive and negative coefficients by different values.

- Does normalizing positive values by one number and negative values to another number have issues?  What issues?
- What benefit would there be to normalizing positive values by one number and negative values by another. When would this be the right thing to do?  Maybe there is some advantage in terms of precision?

Comment: The difference is likely an insignificant offset error; note that fixed point 2’s complement typically includes an offset error since the negative going peak is one more than the positive ($-2^{b-1}$ to $+2^{b-1}-1$). This introduces a DC value and if DC is not in our bandwidth then it doesn’t matter. And even if it is, the offset is less than the precision so likely also insignificant. However can you detail a specific example showing the result with both approaches in case I am missing something?